# Getopts option processing, Is it possible to add a non hyphenated [FILE]?

Tags: shell, parameter, options, dash, getopts

I'm using `getopts` for all of my scripts that require advanced option parsing, and It's worked great with `dash`.  I'm familiar with the standard basic `getopts` usage, consisting of `[-x]` and `[-x OPTION]`.

Is it possible to parse options like this?

```
 dash_script.sh FILE -x -z -o OPTION
 ## Or the inverse?
 dash_script.sh -x -z -o OPTION FILE
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Script arguments usually come after options. Take a look at any other commands such as `cp` or `ls` and you will see that this is the case.

So, to handle:

```
dash_script.sh -x -z -o OPTION FILE
```

you can use `getopts` as shown below:

```
while getopts xzo: option
do
    case "$option" in
        x) echo "x";;
        z) echo "z";;
        o) echo "o=$OPTARG";;
    esac
done
shift $(($OPTIND-1))
FILE="$1"
```

After processing the options, `getopts` sets `$OPTIND` to the index of the first non-option argument which in this case is `FILE`.

Comment: I'm going to test this one out, looks like a good implementation.

Comment: This is perfect, exactly how I would want the options to go!  Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 2):

Getopt will rearrange the parameters and put all non option parameters at the end, after `--`:

```
$ getopt -o a: -- nonoption-begin -a x nonoption-middle -a b nonoption-end
-a 'x' -a 'b' -- 'nonoption-begin' 'nonoption-middle' 'nonoption-end'
```

If you really need know that a nonoption parameter is at the beginning, you can check whether `$1` is an option, and if it isn't extract it, before you call `getopt`:

```
if [ ${1#-} = $1 ]; then
  NONOPTION=$1
  shift
fi
ARGS=$(getopt ...)
```

Comment: Although my answer was about getopt (not getopts), I'll leave it because the part about extracting the first parameter is still valid.